# If div width increases style the other div using only CSS

Tags: css, sass

Please go through the below screenshots. It is working fine if the div width or text count is less. If div width is getting increased then right side text design is breaking.

I need to write a condition using only SASS or css saying that if the div width increases bring the beside text to down the box as per in the screenshot. If div width increases then only it has to come down. Else it is working properly.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COhqp.png)

[Currently showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guOOc.jpg)

Can Please anyone help here?

```
<div class="article__meta live-blog-article-meta">
            <div class="article-slug article-slug--article-page theme__background-color">
            <span class="article-slug__copy">Advertisement Feature</span>
        </div>

    <div class="article__name-date">
                    <div class="article__author theme__copy-color">
                <span class="article__author-name theme__copy-color">
                    RAMASAMY AYYAPPAN               </span>
            </div>

        <div class="article__time">
            <div class="article__published">
                <span>14th February 2017,</span>
                <span class="article__timestamp">6:40 am</span>
            </div>

                    <div class="article__updated">
                <span>Updated: 14th February 2017,</span>
                <span class="article__timestamp">7:39 am</span>
            </div>
                </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your html and css code

Comment: Please put some code.

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look and please help. Please click on the link. You will get to know the expected result and current result. there are 2 screenshots

Comment: Please include code (HTML and CSS) that will allow us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Or give us example in some website or event the html snippet that is here so we can help you better